# Show that $U_i \rightarrow U_{i+e}, x \mapsto x^p$ is an isomorphism

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> Show that $U_i \rightarrow U_{i+e}, x \mapsto x^p$ is an isomorphism?

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with uniformizer $\pi$, prime $\mathfrak p$, and ramification index $e = e(\mathfrak p/p)$.  Let $U_i = 1 + \mathfrak p^i$.

> If $i > \frac{e}{p-1}$, show that the map $x \mapsto x^p$ is an isomorpism $U_i \rightarrow U_{i+e}$.

Given an element $1 + \pi^{i+e}x \in U_{i+e}$, $x \in \mathcal O_K$, I tried used the following version of Hensel's lemma using the polynomial $f(X) = X^p - 1 - \pi^{i+e}x$, to show the surjectivity of the given map.

> Hensel's lemma: if $\alpha_0 \in \mathcal O_K$ satisfies $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(f(\alpha_0)) > \nu_{\mathfrak p}(f'(\alpha_0)^2)$, there is a unique $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(\alpha - \alpha_0) > \nu_{\mathfrak p}(f(\alpha_0)) - \nu_{\mathfrak p}(f'(\alpha_0)^2)$.

Take $\alpha_0 = 1$.  Then $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(f(\alpha_0)) = \nu_{\mathfrak p}(-\pi^{i+e}x) \geq i + e$, and $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(f'(\alpha_0)^2) = 2 \nu_{\mathfrak p}(p) = 2e$.

So $f$ should have a $p$th root $\alpha$, with $\alpha - 1 \in \mathfrak p^{i - e}$.  But this still doesn't work, because I need a $p$th root in $U_i$.  Any hints?

Comment: Maybe use the fact that $U_n \rightarrow (\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^\times, \ \ x \mapsto x\ \mathrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{p}^n$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Doesn't that just send any $1 + x \pi^n$ to $1$?

Comment: Eh, sorry it was meant to be $\mathcal{O}^\times/U_n \rightarrow(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^\times$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $p=b{\pi}^e$, with $v(b)=0$, and $y\in U_{i+e}$ under the form $y=1+a{\pi}^{i+e}$, with $v(a)\ge 0$. We look for $x=1+c{\pi}^i \in U_i$ s.t. $y=x^p$, i.e. $1+a{\pi}^{i+e}=1+pc{\pi}^i+...+c^p {\pi}^{ip}$. Because $i>e/(p-1)$, all the terms in the RHS other than the two first ones have valuation $>i+e$, so our equation can be written $a=bc+f(c)$, where $f(c)$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are all divisible by $\pi$. Reduction mod $\pi$ gives the linear relation $\bar a=\bar b . \bar c$, where $\bar b \neq 0$, hence the existence of a unique solution $\bar c$. We conclude using Hensel's lemma.